# How to check if all the data is inserted or not in mongodb cloud using python

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe

I am new MongoDB and trying to insert data into MongoDB cloud shared version using python as

```
df = pd.read_csv('FitBit data.csv')

data = df.to_dict()
db = client['mydatabase']
col = db['Data_fitbit']
col.insert_many([data])
```

i thing data inserted is way more less than the actual data. How check the number of rows inserted.

Comment: You are inserting a single element, `to_dict()` create a single dictionary. this means as long as your code doesn't throw an error you inserted a single item.

Comment: @Tom that's right, means i need to check data in the dictionary created ?

Comment: yes, are you saving it like that on purpose?